# Disable puts output in RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec, progress-bar, output, stdout

I got a ProgressBar with some logs, and it is being displayed on each iteration. When I run RSpec, I'd like that only the results to get displayed (only `.` or  `f`, and not the output that my app may display).

Between, I'm not using rails, so I don't have environments.

**I got this:**

[image]

**And I want this:**

[image]

My code is deadly simple:

```
progress_bar = ProgressBar.create(:total => nil)
progress_bar.increment
progress_bar.log "New Page added on depth #{depth}! #{url}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stub logging in tests:

```
ProgressBar.any_instance.stub(:log)
```

if there are more than 1 test for this action, put it in `before(:each)`:

```
before(:each) do
  ProgressBar.any_instance.stub(:log)
end
```

If you use `progressbar` gem, it will create `ProgressBar::Base` instance, so you should use:

```
ProgressBar::Base.any_instance.stub(:log)
```

Comment: Thanks; bt I put this in the `spec_helper` file, in the config block (config.before(:each)), and unfortunately, it doesn't work

Comment: still doesn't work, I checked thoroughfully, and it does not work :(

Comment: I put it in a before(:each) , and even in a before(:all), to no avail

Comment: please show your method and spec for this method, otherwise I can't say

Comment: Here you go:
http://www.noelshack.com/2014-49-1417518467-screen1.png
http://www.noelshack.com/2014-49-1417518467-screen2.png
http://www.noelshack.com/2014-49-1417518467-screen3.png
http://www.noelshack.com/2014-49-1417518467-screen5.png
http://www.noelshack.com/2014-49-1417518467-screen7.png

Comment: Lets discuss in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66022/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-27246902-disable-puts-output-in-rspec)

Answer (score 4):

`any_instance` is deprecated since RSpec 3.

Also the ProgressBar inner classes seem to have changed. This did it for me :

```
before(:each) do
  allow_any_instance_of(ProgressBar::Output).to receive(:stream).and_return(double().as_null_object)
end
```